# flare_flutter animation display issues

Tags: flutter, animation, dart, flare

The issue is the animation can't be displayed but only image can be shown. There is only part of code about BottomAnimeLoader right here. So please help me figure what's happen why only the static image is right here. (using flutter framework and dart language)

[the animation is static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2MpL.png)

```
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomAnimeLoader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomAnimeLoaderState createState() => _BottomAnimeLoaderState();
}

class _BottomAnimeLoaderState extends State<BottomAnimeLoader> {
  String _animationName = "new";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: FlareActor(
            "assets/flr/success.flr",
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            animation: _animationName,
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the official example's flr file to simulate this case because I do not have your flr file
If you have wrong `_animationName` name, then it will become static image 
In official example, the `_animationName` is `idle`, if I change it to `new` it will become static image
Please correct your `_animationName`, for example the following  https://rive.app/a/pollux/files/flare/success-check `_animationName` is `Untitled`

[image]

working demo

[image]

full test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';

class BottomAnimeLoader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomAnimeLoaderState createState() => _BottomAnimeLoaderState();
}

class _BottomAnimeLoaderState extends State<BottomAnimeLoader> {
  String _animationName = "success";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: FlareActor(
            "assets/flr/success.flr",
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            animation: _animationName,
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: BottomAnimeLoader(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I made it!